# how to t-type splice power wires to add a new outlets?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I need to install a new old work outlet box on my drywall.

I know the existing wires goes behind the drywall where I intend to install the socket box, **however**, there is no existing outlet, connection box, or lighting fixture I can use as the source in the reachable range.

I could cut the existing wires, and insert the socket box, which will add additional knots to the circuit. The only option seems to make t-type connections from the existing wires.

what is the best way to do it, or any suggestions?

thanks,
Heinz

Comment: Cables always get cut at junction boxes. There are no tap-style connectors in house wiring.  I hope their aren't any "knots", either. :)

Comment: T splices went out with K & T.  :-)

Comment: What is the "reachable range" for you? And where are you on this planet even?

Answer (score 6):

The usual solution is **not** "t-type connections". You normally can't do that inside walls. Assuming you don't have ~ 2 feet of slack in the wires, the way to do this is with **two** boxes a few feet apart. The key is that each box has to have several inches of wire inside the box. Hopefully you can do this without making *three* holes, but conceptually:

Note: You should actually cut all the holes at one time, otherwise you may "lose" the cable when you cut it. Also, **be really, really sure, that power is off before you cut the cable, or you may be in for a shocking experience.**

- Hole # 1

Cut the cable.

- Hole # 2 - at least a foot to the left of hole # 1.

Route the left section of the cut wires into a new box.

Add a new 3-foot section of cable and connect that as well (pigtail or in on one side, out on the other).

- Hole # 3 - at least a foot to the right of hole # 1.

Route the right section of the cut wires into a new box.

Connect the new 3-foot section of cable as well (pigtail or in on one side, out on the other).

If having 3 receptacle boxes is OK then you could put a receptacle into hole # 1 as well, with one new section of cable from # 2 to # 1 and one from # 1 to # 3. If you don't like patching drywall, that may be less work than patching hole # 1.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed suggestion, accept it.